# How to ONLY print stdout/stderr from failing tests, not failing packages?

Tags: go, testing, logging

If a single test fails, the entire package fails and thus the output from all tests within that package are printed. This is cumbersome since the functions being tested have logging in them. I could suppress the logging entirely but that makes it difficult to track down the root when a test fails because my log output has a ton of extra noise.

Is it possible to only print the output from a specific test that fails, instead of printing the entire package?

The first solution that comes to mind is to wrap each test in a function which redirects the log output to a buffer, and then only print the buffer if the test it's wrapping fails, but that obviously adds extra boilerplate to my tests that I'd rather not have to add.

Comment: "my log output has a ton of extra noise" - that's probably something you should address. You can also run individual tests if you need to using `-run`.

Comment: @Adrian These tests are being automated by Travis. I can selectively choose which ones to test if I need to fix them

Comment: Then your best bet would be to start by cutting the noise from your logs.